# registerReceiver programmatically not working

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Im developing a service which will start every time user turns screen on / user present / boot completed. I have researched some on google and found that, the ACTION_SCREEN_ON is only registered programmatically so I have followed by:

```
private void registerAction() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)
        AutoStart mReceiver = new AutoStart();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }
```

And called the function inside my `onCreate` method of the first Activity. At first, everything worked fine on my SAMSUNG device. The problem is when I test my application on my HTC and LG device, NO broadcast signal sent and look like the receiver had not been registered at all. So I did a little modification, I added the receiver into manifest file:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".AutoStart"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Now both my HTC, SAMSUNG and LG devices worked. However, on the SAMSUNG, the broadcast signals sent TWICE. So both receiver on the manifest file and programmatically registered !?!. Any ideas on this problem? why my HTC and LG devices not working?

Another thing, look like those signals sometimes don't work (I tested alone in SAMSUNG device) and I don't know why. Is there anyway to guarantee the broadcast signals sent all the time?

Here is my code of the receiver:

```
public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Context context;
    private static final String TAG = "AutoStart";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        DLog.d(TAG, "Auto start at any action screen on - user present - boot completed");
    }
// more functions, not related to the question
}
```

Hope I made myself clear and would be appreciate any helps. Leave the comments if there are any information needed.

Comment: are you registering in Service or Activity?

Comment: @GopalRao I registering it in Activity

Comment: SCREEN_ON receiver should be registered dynamically where as BOOT_COMPLETED receiver should be registered statically in manifest...